# Return type JsonResult is not working in .Net 6?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, webapi, .net-6.0

I have created one basic HTTPPost method where i am returning Json(object) but Json is giving me compile time error as Json is not present in class

[image: Code snippets]

Answer (score 3):

Use `IActionResult` instead of `JsonResult` (`JsonResult` implements `IActionResult` anyway), and return `Ok(o)` intead of `Json(o)`.

The `Json()` method is from old ASP.NET, in modern ASP.NET Core you use the `Ok()` method.

Answer (score 2):

by default the controller will automatically return json

change return type to IActionResult

and just return whatever it is and it should automatically return it as Json